# Finding particular path in directory in Python

Tags: python, path, subdirectory, os.system, scandir

How could I find the path of the directory which contains a date like 20170423 ? meaning, it could be any date, but i want to have that specific path until i get a folder that contains a date.. There may be several sub-directories along the way that contain that pattern, but that's a special case, where i would need to give more precision, like the content of the folder to select the proper one. give it a shot if you d like for the special case, but for the case where i know that only one folder along the way contains that pattern, the way i start is :

```
 directPaths_list  =  [f.path for f in os.scandir( start ) if f.is_dir()   ]
```

This gives me all the paths from the start folder, to the end. Now, i would like to return the paths that have the date pattern in them, and in particular one, that has let's say whose int(folder_name) is < datetime.datetime.today()

I could come up with a rough solution, but SO has people with very good skills at coming up with succint elegant solutions, so there it is.. any idea? thanks!

for example, for the path start= C:/ this would return C:\Users\abc\def\ghi\20170412

I was thinking something like this could work:

```
[f.path for f in os.scandir('C:\\Users\\abc\\def\\ghi\\') if f.is_dir() and str(f.path).endswith(str(2),-2,-1) ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the date `20170423` is a file named accordingly.
Then you could use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
start = "C:\\Users\\abc\\"

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename == "20170412":
            filename = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            print(filename)
            print(dirpath)
```

If only a single file exists `C:\Users\abc\def\ghi\20170412` then the above would output:

```
C:\Users\abc\def\ghi\20170412
C:\Users\abc\def\ghi\
```

You can of course change the if statement to fit whether you want to check `filename.startswith("2017")` or anything else.

**Warning:** If you do `start = "C:\\"` then this is most likely gonna take a **looong time to finish.** Because it is going to run through every single directory on the C drive.

You can equally change `for filename in filenames`

```
for dirname in dirnames:
    if dirname == "20170412":
        dirname = os.path.join(dirpath, dirname )
        print(dirname)
        print(dirpath)
```

Thus if `C:\Users\abc\def\ghi\20170412` is actually a directory, then the above would output the same as before:

```
C:\Users\abc\def\ghi\20170412
C:\Users\abc\def\ghi\
```

> I was hoping for something more succinct

You could still pack it into a list comprehension if that's what you call more brief.

```
files = [os.path.join(dir, f) for dir, dirs, files in os.walk(start) for f in files if f == "20170412"]
```

Comment: thanks! but i want a directory, should i just use your solution with 
`for dirname in dirnames`   
and also `dirname<datetime.datetime.today()`
?

Comment: Yes you can equally do `for dirname in dirnames`. When you've found the file or directory, then the parent directory will be `dirpath`.

Comment: nice!, to your comment about if i start at C:\\ i could actually do bottom up search with  `os.walk("C:\\Users\...", topdown=False)`

Comment: Yes you indeed can. It will however still take a long time if you start at C:\.

Comment: you got it buddy, fast and easy. I was hoping for something more succint, but this works, and perhaps is less error prone. so thanks!

Comment: I would already call it quite succinct. However you can still make a list comprehension if that's what you want (add it to the answer). I don't really know what you mean by "less error prone". You could always make a function `find_files_by_name(start, name)` if that's what you wanted.

Comment: well would give you one more check but cant :)