# Setting universal path to file in Python (without for loop)

Tags: python, path

I'm trying to set up my working directory so that it will be universal on all machines – but without for loops. I'm using the following code, based on this thread: [Finding particular path in directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553742/finding-particular-path-in-directory-in-python)

```
import os
try:                                                                                                                        
    start = '/Users'                                                                                                        
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename == "US_Accidents_Dec19.csv":
                filename = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                os.chdir(dirpath)
except:
    pass


try:
    start1 = "C:\\Users"
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start1):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename == "US_Accidents_Dec19.csv":
                filename = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                os.chdir(dirpath)
except:
    pass
```

How would I do this without using for loops? Makes for a slow script.

Comment: well, os.walk is slow. please say what exactly are you trying to accomplish. if you want current directory path just os.getcwd() is enough.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is creating a `project_path` variable which will be the machine's local path to the project. It can be done by creating a file - say *project_path.py* - containing

```py
import os

project_path: str = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

So your project looks something like

```
 - __init__.py 
 - some_folder
 |-- some_script.py
 |-- data_file
 - some_other_script.py
 - project_path.py
```

Then you can easily use it as follows:

```py
from project_path import project_path

with open(f'{project_path}/some_folder/data_file', 'r') as file:
    # do some stuff


# In your case
with open(f'{project_path}/US_Accidents_Dec19.csv', 'r') as file:
    ...
```

This will work regardless of the machine's architecture, os, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pathlib library. It should take care of the formatting for you.
Assuming the folder with the file is somewhere in your own home directory, this code should do the trick:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path


generator = Path.home().glob('**/US_Accidents_Dec19.csv')
wd = list(generator)[0]
os.chdir(wd)
```

The pathlib library can work with paths independent of your operating system. `Path.home()` finds your user directory, e.g. '\Users\MyAccount' or 'C:\Users\MyAccount'.

The `glob()` function can find files based on patterns for you. `**/` means search all subfolders.

If you want to search not only your users' directory, but all users directories, simply do `Path.home().parent.glob('**/US_Accidents_Dec19.csv')`

If the file you are looking for can be found in the same folder or in subfolders relative to your script, try using `Path(__file__).resolve()` to get the complete path to your file and then use glob on this.

```
generator = Path(__file__).resolve().glob('**/US_Accidents_Dec19.csv')
wd = list(generator)[0]
os.chdir(wd)
```

The `glob()` function returns a generator object. A generator object can be turned into a list with `list(obj)` or you can iterate over it with a for-loop as if it was a list.